# CakePdf Plugin - how to write barcode and qr code

Tags: cakephp, pdf, plugins, qr-code

Just installed the [CakePDF plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf), and using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) as the engine.  Now I'm trying to write bar codes and QR codes, but nothing I've tried has worked.

I can get bar codes and qr codes to work if I use the [TCPDF engine directly](http://www.tcpdf.org/), but now that I'm trying to use the plugin, I'm not sure what to do other that just rewrite what I did with the engine directly... which makes me wonder what the point of the plugin would be then.

Am I missing something obvious?  Can I create bar codes and qr codes via TCPDF if I'm using the CakePDF Plugin or should I just scrap the plugin and go directly w/ the engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CakePDF plugin is a HTML to PDF wrapper, nothing more nothing less. Look at the source, it doesn't support all the nifty features of the individual PDF engines, it's purely "*pass HTML to engine and return the output*".

The point of the plugin is to integrate this easily with CakePHP views. If you need more control, then you'll usually need to to make use of the engines directly.

That being said, TCPDF supports a special `<tcpdf>` tag to invoke methods via HTML, which might suit your needs.

Example:

```
<?php
$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array(
    'CODE 39', 'C39', '', '', 80, 30, 0.4,
    array(
        'position' => 'S',
        'border' => true,
        'padding' => 4,
        'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
        'bgcolor' => array(255,255,255),
        'text' => true,
        'font' => 'helvetica',
        'fontsize' => 8,
        'stretchtext' => 4
    ),
    'N'
));
?>
<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="<?php echo $params; ?>" />
```

See also [**TCPDF Examples: call TCPDF methods in HTML**](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_049.phps)

Comment: I guess that's what I thought I might have to do, but - this example doesn't work.  It throws an error, and upon looking further, there IS no TCPDF_STATIC anywhere in the plugin or it's vendor folders.  Am I better off just not using the plugin at all?   Or do I have to include some specific file(s) that aren't in the plugin? Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like the TCPDF library that ships with the plugin is totally outdated, the mentioned functionality was introduced in version 6 if I'm not mistaken. Not sure if you should use the plugin, it depends on your specific use case. However in any case I'd strongly suggest to use the latest TCPDF version, no matter it's directly or via the plugin. Not sure if the plugin works with the latest version though. @Dave