# How to make header using CakePDF with mPDF engine?

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf, mpdf

I'm having trouble with implemeting HTML header in PDF,
mPDF has function `SetHTMLHeader()` but i don't know how to call it from CakePDF
my code is:

```
$this->pdfConfig = array(
            'orientation '=> 'landscape',
            'download' => true,
            'filename' => 'test.pdf');

$CakePdf = new CakePdf(Configure::read('CakePdf'));
$CakePdf->template('corporate', 'default');
$pdf = $CakePdf->output();
$pdf = $CakePdf->write(APP . 'webroot' . DS . 'files' . DS . 'test.pdf');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePdf Plugin - how to write barcode and qr code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927516/cakepdf-plugin-how-to-write-barcode-and-qr-code)

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate, but it's essentially the very same problem... mPDF has control tags too which might be suitable, like for example [**`<sethtmlpageheader>`**](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=179).